# Passing an NSManagedObject Effectively through Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I have quite a complicated setup in my app that involves an embedded `UISplitViewController` which feeds a bunch of `UIViewControllers`.

What I am needing to do is pass an `NSManagedObject` through the embedded `UISplitViewController` so I can access it in my separate detail' `UIViewControllers`.

I have attached an image of my storyboard with some awesome annotations....[image]

This is my prepareForSegue function at the minute, this is in the View Controller where I already have my NSManagedObject, I am looking to pass it to the first SurveyViewController so it can get passed on:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    println("Sender is \(sender)")

    if segue.identifier == SurveyIdentifier {


//            let nav : UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
//            let itemVC: BACUploaderViewController =  nav.topViewController as! BACUploaderViewController

        let surveyViewController: SurveyViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SurveyViewController


        println("survey view controller: \(surveyViewController)")


//            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MasterViewController {
//                
//                destination.workItem = sender as? Work

//            }
      }

}
```

I am fairly sure that I have to access my `MasterViewController` from here by drilling down through the View Hierarchy, but not sure on how to achieve this effectively?

On a side note, the segue does work, I am presented with the correct views, but it pushes the view onto the screen twice and I'm not sure why, I can upload a gif of this if seeing what I am talking about in action might make more sense?

Comment: Instead of drilling down, you should pass your `NSManagedObject`  to the viewcontrollers through dependency injection.

Comment: Now that sounds like a far better solution,  how would I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "reach down" through the hierarchy of view controllers, to get a reference to the table view controller titled "Sections" in the storyboard.

From `prepareForSegue` in your `SurveyViewController`:

```
    // the destination of the "embed" segue will be the split view controller
    let splitVC : UISplitViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UISplitViewController
    // in a UISplitViewController, viewControllers[0] represents the Master view controller
    // in your case that is a UINavigationController...
    let navVC: UINavigationController =  splitVC.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    // In a UINavigationController, topViewController represents the visible VC
    // In your case that's the Sections table view controller...
    let sectionsVC : SectionsViewController = navVC.topViewController as! SectionsViewController
    // (replace "SectionsViewController" with the correct class name)
    sectionsVC.object = yourNSManagedObject
```

This passes the object to the Sections view controller.  You can pass the object to the final VCs (the bad boys!) in the `prepareForSegue` of the Sections view controller.  You can't do it earlier, because they are not instantiated before then.

As to why the view might be pushed onto screen twice, my only guess is that you might be using `performSegueWithIdentifier` from within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of a table view, when the segue is also linked directly to the prototype cell.

Comment: thanks for the response! Um, thing is i'm getting this error Could not cast value of type 'my.SurveyViewController' (0x179058) to 'UISplitViewController' (0x36c35244). I know why it is, its because I have that surveyViewController as the View that has the container that has the UISplitViewController in it, if you follow? So then my segue.destination is the SurveyViewController not the UISplitViewController, how do I access the UISplitViewController?

Comment: absolutely ignore me, i realised i had to go further back and make sure my NSManageObject wsa being passed into the SurveyViewController, and I had missed where you said "From prepareForSegue in your SurveyViewController:" I cannot upvote this enough, problem solved!! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

println("Sender is \(sender)")

if segue.identifier == SurveyIdentifier {


//            let nav : UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
//            let itemVC: BACUploaderViewController =  nav.topViewController as! BACUploaderViewController

    let surveyViewController: SurveyViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SurveyViewController
***********************
    surveyViewController.managedObject = self.managedObjectContext
 ************************
//            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MasterViewController {
//                
//                destination.workItem = sender as? Work

//            }
  }

}
```

You can have an optional named `managedObject` in your `SurveyViewController` and then inject your `managedObjectContext` object from `MasterViewController` to `SurveyViewController`. This code snippet is written keeping in mind that you are in `MasterViewController`

Comment: Is this not the same as declaring an NSManagedObject in the destination view class and then assigning the passed object to it, e.g in my destination i'd have  var object : NSManagedObjectSubClass? and then in the segue have destination.object = NSManagedObjectSubClass.. much like I have commented out?