# Class property value returns nil after changing value

Tags: ios, swift, class, core-data

I am trying to pass data from my `CollectionViewController` to the `MasterViewController` which is part of a `SplitViewController`. The only way I can think of doing this is by creating a `class` in a separate file to save the managed object as the class property value to then reference the class in the `SplitViewController`. (As I cannot use a `prepareForSegue` method as I am segueing to a `SplitViewController` not directly to the `MasterViewController`).

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know this is occurring because the `class` `property` holds a value of `nil` therefore the `SplitViewController` crashes. But when outputting the values in the `CollectionViewController` method the values **do not** return nil so why has the class property got a value of nil in the `SplitViewController`?

I am new to Swift but isn't a class a reference type so I change its properties and access them from another controller :/

This is how my project is set up;

[image]

**My Class:**

```
class ObjectClass {
var selectedObject: Object!
}
```

**CollectionViewController**

Here I fetch all the `managed objects` into an `array` to display then use the prepare for segue to store the managed object to the `class` `property`. But it does not seem to be saving anything as I get `property` value of `nil` in the next controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showObject" {

    let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
    let selectedObject = objects[indexPath.row]

    let objectClass = ObjectClass()
    objectClass.selectedObject = selectedObject

    print("selectedObject value \(selectedObject) and objectClass value \(objectClass.selectedObject)")

    //outputs values fine 

    }
}
```

**MasterViewController**

The app now crashes because using the class property value is nil and not the managed object.

class NotesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

```
let objectClass = ObjectClass()

var selectedObject: Object!

@IBOutlet weak var title: UIButton!

func setData() {
    selectedObject = objectClass.selectedObject
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    setData()
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setData()
    self.splitViewController?.delegate = self
    self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible


    print("Selected Object Details \(selectedObject)")
    //Prints Nil

    title.text = "\(selectedObject.title)"

}
```

Comment: You *can* use prepareForSegue - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32341305/3985749) to a very similar question.

Comment: Thank you !! Sometimes it's hard to find the answer to something you don't know the question to.